# Python fills string with unnessecary characters

Tags: python

In this Python code, I have the following problem. When the result is displayed, I get a bunch of zeros in the result (see below) - otherwise, the result is correct (the ending numbers of the string). Can anyone spot the error?

```
def menu():
    binNumber = ''
    decNumber = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    decNumber, binNumber = decimalToBinary(decNumber, binNumber)

    printResult(binNumber)

def decimalToBinary(dec, bin):
    while dec != 0:
        remain = dec % 2
        dec = dec / 2
        if remain > 0.5:
            bin += '1'
        else:
            bin += '0'
    return dec, bin

def printResult(binNumber):
    print("The binary notation is:", binNumber[::-1]) # the last part is to reverse the string

menu()
```

This is the result if I type "2"

> The binary notation is:
>   00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
decNumber = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))
```

to

```
decNumber = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
```

And use integer division. Instead of

```
dec = dec / 2
```

use

```
dec = dec // 2
```

with these changes, I get the following output

```
The binary notation is: 10
```

Comment: I actually had it that way at first, but that didn't change anything. I'm pretty sure the error is in that while loop

Comment: Were you using the integer division as well? I dont think so.

Comment: Whoa. Actually, that worked just fine. But I also tried to change the condition in the while loop to "while dec >= 1:" and it seemed to do the job too. Any suggestion to what is a better solution?

Comment: Small addition to your answer `if remain > 0.5:` -> `if remain:`

Answer (score 0):

@Ragnar, before everything I should mention that your code is wrong. I tried to convert 12 and 41 with this code and it failed. To get a complete help, I suggest you to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838994/float-to-binary).