# Custom binary representation of fixed point number

Tags: python-3.x, binary, fixed-point

Is there a way to obtain the binary representation of a number in Python? It has to be able to represent negative numbers as well. I already tried the function from numpy `np.binary_repr(Decimal(-1))` but it results in an error. To be precise - I want to somehow obtain the binary representations of fixed point numbers (positive and negative), so I can put them into Verilog code.

Let's say I have the number `1,5` in decimal. I want to write it with two bit precision and three integer bits and a sign. In binary this would be `0001,10`, so basically `000110`. I could do this easily by hand, but the problem is that I also have negative ones and furthermore they don't have a finite expansion after the point (like `1/3` in decimal)

To be more precise: If I have a number like `-1.5` in decimal a sign, fraction precision of two, and integer precision of two, I expect the number `110,10` to be the output - the first digit is the sign, the next two the number, the next two are the fraction.

Comment: interesting, but can you show us input & expected ouput ? what does Verilog has to do with python internal number representation? I think you want to "emulate" Verilog code expected number representation instead.

Comment: It's not about pythons internal number representation. Let's say I have the number `1,5` in decimal. I want to write it with two bit precision and three integer bits and a sign. In binary this would be `0001,10`, so basically `000110`. I could do this easily by hand, but the problem is that I also have negative ones and furthermore they don't have a finite expansion after the point (like `1/3` in decimal).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Float to binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838994/float-to-binary)

Comment: @kamik423 Nope it's fixed point here and not floating point.

Answer (score 2):

`bin(number)` might be the function you are looking for. It supports negative numbers, but has a somewhat peculiar format

```
>>> bin(4)
'0b100'
>>> bin(-3)
'-0b11'
>>> bin(10000000)
'0b100110001001011010000000'
```

You could build something like this to convert it to a more common notation:

```
def binary(number):
    b = bin(number)
    if b[0] == '-':
        return '-' + b[3:]
    else:
        return b[2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create fixed-point number throught various fixed-point arithmetic library like [numfi](https://numfi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```py
>>> from numfi import numfi  
>>> x = numfi(-1.5,1,5,2) 
>>> x.bin  
array(['11010'], dtype='<U5')
>>> x.bin_
array(['110.10'], dtype='<U6')
```

But if all you need is transforming single decimal number to fixed length binary representation and no arithmetic operation, you can just use `np.binary_repr(x,width)`

```py
np.binary_repr(np.round(num*(2**f)).astype(int), width=w) 
# num=-1.5, f=2, w=5 (2 fraction, 2 integer, 1 signed) for your example
```

you can use `np.floor`/`np.ceil`/`.astype(int)` to replace `np.round`, for different rounding method

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **fxpmath** module for that.

The repo website is: https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

x = Fxp(-1.5, True, 5, 2)   # (val, signed, n_word, n_frac)

print(x.bin())
```

Result:

```
11010
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package. With this package you can convert binary-fraction strings into floats and vice-versa.

Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import Binary
>>> str(Binary(-1.5))
'-0b1.1'
>>> float(Binary("-1.1"))
-1.5
```

It has many more helper functions to manipulate binary strings such as: shift, add, fill, to_exponential, invert...

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.