# How to convert bin to float using 64bit IEE754,

Tags: python, floating-point, binary

I would to convert a float to binary repr. then convert back the binary repr. to float in `python`.

For the first part *float to binary*, I am using [Float to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838994/float-to-binary?rq=1) @Ozbolt answer,

```
def float_to_bin(x):
  if x == 0:
    return "0" * 64
  w, sign = (float.hex(x), 0) if x > 0 else (float.hex(x)[1:], 1)
  mantissa, exp = int(w[4:17], 16), int(w[18:])
  return "{}{:011b}{:052b}".format(sign, exp + 1023, mantissa)
```

Which work very good, for example calling :

```
float_to_bin(10.24)
```

answer:

```
0100000000100100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111011
```

But how to reverse the process (to do *binary to float*)? I expect something like:

`bin_to_float("0100000000100100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111011")`

which answer:

```
10.24
```

Comment: The [answer by Martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8762541/100297) contains a `bin_to_float()` function exactly as you describe.

Comment: Thank you, you save my night ! Regards