# Swift native formatting in numeric bases

Tags: swift

I was reading the answer to this question - [Swift native functions to have numbers as hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings) - and that is exactly what I want to do.  However, when I try this in a playground:

```
let str = String(num: 123.55, radix: 16);
print(str)
```

This is printed:

```
(123.55, 16)
```

Why is it formatting it that way?

The same thing happens for what it's worth if I use a whole number, E.G., 123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the conversation more closely and it was the 'num' label that broke it.  If I use String(123, radix: 16) it works fine.  Fractions do NOT work, however.  I got a runtime error with String(123.55, radix: 16).

EDIT:  As nhgrif points out below, this is now a compiler error, not a runtime error - so it should have never been allowed.  This is true as of XCode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005).  I believe what is going on is with the num: label on the first parameter it is creating a tuple, then calling the String initializer which converts the tuple to it's string representation.  I personally would have expected that to look like this:

`let str = String((num: 1, radix: 2));`

Which the compiler treats the same way (same result output).

Comment: Why you answer your question if it's not an answer really? Please try to put this in an comment if you not solve the problem yet!!

Comment: Are you pointing out that I did not mark the answer as an answer, or that I did not answer it properly?  This is the actual answer to my question, though there are still many things about this I don't get.

Comment: My point is that your answer is not complete, because the error you point regarding the `num` parameter was pointed in every answer. Nevertheless regarding the conversion of `Double` numbers to another base in my answer I point you in the direction of how to do it, because it's not supported yet.

Comment: No other answer points to the num label on the first argument of the initializer - that is the problem the root question points to so this is the answer.  The other answers point to not being able to format non-integer types with a radix other than  10 - which while true, was not the original question - it was only a distraction.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the Swift compiler or the `init` of the `String` type in this case has not a base conversion function implemented to convert from `Double`, `Float` to another base, you can follow some approaches explained in this question [How to convert float number to Binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954498/how-to-convert-float-number-to-binary) adn this [article](http://www.avrams.ro/convert-real-numbers.html)   and do it for yourself.

And the way of call the `init` is in the following way:

```
let num = 12355
let str = String(num, radix: 16)
print(str) // prints "3043"
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

That your code even compiles (or is interpreted by the Playground) is a compiler bug.  It could also be a sign that you're not on the most up to date version of Xcode, or that you need to clean & rebuild.

The initializer you are trying to use is only defined for integer types.

> ```
> extension String {
>     /// Create an instance representing `v` in base 10.
>     public init<T : _SignedIntegerType>(_ v: T)
>     /// Create an instance representing `v` in base 10.
>     public init<T : UnsignedIntegerType>(_ v: T)
>     /// Create an instance representing `v` in the given `radix` (base).
>     ///
>     /// Numerals greater than 9 are represented as roman letters,
>     /// starting with `a` if `uppercase` is `false` or `A` otherwise.
>     public init<T : _SignedIntegerType>(_ v: T, radix: Int, uppercase: Bool = default)
>     /// Create an instance representing `v` in the given `radix` (base).
>     ///
>     /// Numerals greater than 9 are represented as roman letters,
>     /// starting with `a` if `uppercase` is `false` or `A` otherwise.
>     public init<T : UnsignedIntegerType>(_ v: T, radix: Int, uppercase: Bool = default)
> }
> ```

And on my Xcode, in a Playground, attempting to use this initializer with something that isn't a `_SignedIntegerType` or a `UnsignedIntegerType` produces an error.

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Double, radix: Int)'

[image]

Comment: You are correct in that I got an XCode update yesterday which now says this is an error:  `let str = String(123.55, radix: 16);`  It does however still allow this:  `let str = String(num: 123.55, radix: 16);` which seems weird.  Maybe it thinks it is a tuple because this produces the same output:  `let str2 = (num: 123.55, radix: 16);  print(str2);`

Comment: This isn't meant badly, but I found it funny when I noticed you used the label 'hex' for a binary-formatted string (base-2).